# Order in Enzyme Kinetics

Tags: biochemistry, enzyme-kinetics

In an interview for post-grad level, I was asked to explain the "order" of any generic enzymatic reaction involving [competitive inhibition](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Biological_Chemistry/Book%3A_Biochemistry_Online_(Jakubowski)/08%3A_Transport_and_Kinetics/8.4%3A_Enzyme_Inhibition/Competitive_Inhibition). I assumed that [Michaelis-Menten Kinetics](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Biological_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Biological_Chemistry)/Enzymes/Enzymatic_Kinetics/Michaelis-Menten_Kinetics) holds good and went for "first-order". I also noted that the Lineweaver Burk plots [remain linear](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Enzyme_Inhibition_lineweaver-burk_plots.gif) even in competitive inhibition.

However, they asserted (at the end of the interview) that it would be "second-order" - thoughts?

Comment: It sounds like maybe you weren't including the enzyme in your order? In simple M-M kinetics, the reaction is second order at low S concentrations and only first order when the enzyme is saturated and v=kcat[E]tot. As long as the inhibitor is present at high enough concentration to be relevent, you can't saturate the enzyme with substrate. However, it's only really second order when Km(app)>>[S]

Comment: You have to distinguish overall order from order in [S]. The total order is tricky, it could be third or fourth order if you consider proton concentration and happen to have one or two catalytic groups in the active site with a pKa near the pH. In an interview, there are no right answers, only good or bad arguments to support claims. A linear Lineweaver-Burk plot does not imply first or second order. There is a switch in order depending on whether [S] is << or >> Km(app).